# High Availability/failsafe two different locations

Tags: debian, drbd, pacemaker, gfs2

I am wondering if someone could help with the setup that does not seem so difficult. I am just beginning with the multi-server setup. I apologize if my questions are dumb.

I have two debian servers in different locations. The aim is to create a failsafe and high availability system for apache/mysql/filesystem. Both servers should serve requests(on a domain name or with one ip if possible) together. If one fails(power, hardware, network) the other one should take over all the requests and when the first one is back again it should sync and get back online.

So the questions are:
1) I've been exploring pacemaker/corosync configs, but did not find a good tutorial on using it with different locations (all the howtos are for the same network). Is it a right way to go? One problem that i see is that adding additional servers is not straightforward, many options depend on the number of servers. Also, servers have different ips, how to switch? In internal network you just send the right arp message, but in different nets?

2) For the filesystem I chose drbd(dual-primer) with gfs2. Is it a good solution or should i look somewhere else?

3) Load balancing is not crucial, in this case solving "split brain" is much easier as i understand? Should I give up with load balancing and use master-slave instead?

4) Can I just use mysql internal sync or placing it on drbd-partion is crucial?

Comment: anyone? help, anyone?